# Identify all values each variable can take

Tags: constraint-programming, minizinc

I have an array of variables and a list of linear constraints between them. For each variable, I have a set containing a starting list of valid values for it. Using Minizinc, how can I reduce those sets of starting values down to only the ones that can satisfy the constraints?

A simple example to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve:

```
array[1..2] of var int: xy;
array[1..2] of set of int: xyvalid = [ {1, 5, 7}, 0..9 ];

constraint forall(i in 1..2)( xy[i] in xyvalid[i] );
constraint xy[1] + xy[2] = 7;
```

When I run this with a `solve satisfy` item and print all solutions for `xy`, I get (with horizontal lines removed):

```
[1, 6]
[5, 2]
[4, 3]
[3, 4]
```

What I *want* is to somehow get an array of var set, call it `xypossible`, that in this case would equal `[ {1, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4, 6} ]`. I figure I could define a set of constraints that somehow checks that, for every possible value in `xypossible[1]`, that there's a value in `xypossible[2]` that produces a valid solution, and vice versa, and then solve to maximise the total cardinality of all the sets in `xypossible`, but when my real data is potentially of a scale of a few hundred variables with several dozen linear constraints that's going to be ugly to code and terrible to run.

If there isn't a pretty way to do it as a model, is there a way to capture the information as a result of the solver identifying valid values as part of doing its own job?

Comment: Have you tried modeling it with array[1..2] of set of var int: xy? You are trying to find sets.

Comment: I am, and I expect that ultimately that's what I'll do, but I don't know how to specify the model to produce that array efficiently given an appropriate amount of data.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean that the result should be [{1,5,7},{0,2,6}] since the only possible values of xy[1] are {1,5,7} stated in "xyvalid" array; 0, 2, and 6 are the only values that yield 7 when added to 1,5, and 7. Otherwise, I must have missed something...

Here's a model that might work in the way what you want. Though it requires an maximize objective in order to single out the best solution.

```
% the domains of the two variables
array[1..2] of set of int: xyvalid = [ {1, 5, 7}, 0..9 ];

% the result sets 
array[1..2] of var set of 0..9: z;

% ensure that the largest solution is picked 
solve maximize card(z[1]) + card(z[2]);

constraint
   % get the domains of each variable set 
   forall(i in 1..2)( z[i] subset xyvalid[i] ) /\
   % ensure that for all valid values in z[1] are in z[2] given
   % that j + k = 7 
   forall(j in z[1]) (
       exists(k in z[2]) (j + k = 7)
   ) 
   /\
   % and ensure that all valid values in z[2] are in z[1]
   forall(k in z[2]) (
        exists(j in z[1]) (j + k = 7)
   )
   ;
```

The result is then

```
  z = array1d(1..2 ,[{1,5,7}, {0,2,6}]);
```

Without the maximize objective, there would be 8 solutions:

```
  z = array1d(1..2 ,[{1,5,7}, {0,2,6}]);
  ----------
  z = array1d(1..2 ,[{1,7}, {0,6}]);
  ----------
  z = array1d(1..2 ,[{5,7}, {0,2}]);
  ----------
  z = array1d(1..2 ,[7..7, 0..0]);
  ----------
  z = array1d(1..2 ,[{1,5}, {2,6}]);
  ----------
  z = array1d(1..2 ,[1..1, 6..6]);
  ----------
  z = array1d(1..2 ,[5..5, 2..2]);
  ----------
  z = array1d(1..2 ,[{}, {}]);
  ----------
  ==========
```

(some of these could have been removed by some additional constraints)

My personal approach would probably have been to use your variant and collect the possible values via some external program.

Note: In some CP systems, it is possible to print the domains of the decision variables before labeling (i.e. trying to find the proper valid values). However MiniZinc don't have this feature. And I miss that.

Note 2: I tested the dom() function which gives the domains of a decision variable, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! I've just skimmed your answer so far, but I'll read it more thoroughly when I can and see what I can glean from it.